# IOS what is wrong for my code? Got "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

My code got the error, but I do not know what is wrong with my code, please give me some help, thanks so much.

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
>   Error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

my code is :

```
let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (location, reason, descri) VALUES ('\(location.text!)', '\(reason.text!)', '\(descri.text!)')" //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
```

Comment: Just post the part that contains the line that the error happen

Comment: Any exclamation mark can cause the error. The text property of one of the labels is most likely `nil`.

Comment: I have updated my code, please check, thank you so much.

Comment: Read Apple's free Swift books. Learn what optionals are. ! means "There is an optional, but I'm sure it's not nil. Please crash in the case that it is nil". And that's exactly what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access an optional’s value (if it has one at all), you need to **unwrap** it. An optional value can be unwrapped safely or forcibly. If you force-unwrap an optional, and it didn't have a value, your program will crash with the above message.

This crash can occur with two different kinds of force-unwrap:

**1. Explicit Force Unwrapping**

This is done with the ! operator on an optional.

For example:

```
let anOptionalString: String?
print(anOptionalString!) // <- CRASH
```

As `anOptionalString` is `nil` here, you will get a crash on the line where you force unwrap it.

**2. Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals**

These are defined with a `!`, rather than a `?` after the type.

```
var optionalDouble: Double!  // this value is implicitly unwrapped wherever it's used
```

These optionals are assumed to contain a value. Therefore whenever you access an implicitly unwrapped optional, it will automatically be force unwrapped for you. If it doesn’t contain a value, it will crash.

```
print(optionalDouble) // <- CRASH
```

In order to work out which variable caused the crash, you can hold `⌥` while clicking to show the definition, where you might find the optional type.

[for more details go through this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcs22.gif)

IBOutlets, in particular, are usually implicitly unwrapped optionals. This is because your xib or storyboard will link up the outlets at runtime, after initialization. You should therefore ensure that you’re not accessing outlets before they're loaded in. You also should check that the connections are correct in your storyboard/xib file, otherwise the values will be nil at runtime, and therefore crash when they are implicitly unwrapped.